# why LINQ 2 SQL sometime add a field like select 1 as test, others valid fields

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have to concat 2 linq2sql query and I have an issue since the 2 query doesn't return the same number of columns, what is weird is after a .ToList() on the queries, they can concat without problem.

The reason is, for some linq2sql reason, I have 2 more column named test and test2 which come from 2 left outer join that linq2sql automatically create, something like "select **1 as test,** tablefields"

Is there any good reason for that? how to remove this extra "1 as test" field?

here a few of examples of what it look like: [**google** result for **linq 2 sql "select 1 as test"**](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=linq+2+sql+"select+1+as+test"&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)

Comment: I've seen it, it's weird, as far as I know there's nothing you can do about it.  I've never seen it cause problems - you should post the actual code that's failing if it's breaking your app.

Comment: sadly, I cannot post the actual code that causing it

Comment: Perhaps you should reproduce your symptoms in a sample which you *can* post snippets from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, let's assuming we have 2 tables: `dbo.User` and `dbo.Client`. Each `client` may be connected (or not) to `user`. So `client` records have a nullable foreign key field identifying a `user`.

For the query:

```
var query = context.Clients
      .Select(c => c.User);
```

LINQ will produce something similar to:

```
SELECT [t2].[test], [t2].[Id], [t2].[Username], ...
FROM [dbo].[Client] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS [test], [t1].[Id], [t1].[Username], ...
    FROM [dbo].[User] AS [t1]
    ) AS [t2] ON [t2].[Id] = [t0].[UserId]
```

Since not all `client` records have a matching `user` record, LINQ is creating a query that ensures there will be a row filled with nulls for every userless `client`. This is done by creating an extra dummy column called `[test]`.

So rows which have `[test]` column value set to `1` are really connected to `user` entity.

I suppose this `[test]` column is used by LINQ as a flag that means "hey, here is a client with user defined".

If I decide to rewrite this query, I'll use `user` primary key as the indicator, but it seems for LINQ it is easier to use `[test]` column.

Comment: Thank you! This was a mystery my coworkers and I were attempting to figure out!